# Can't include .hpp file from subproject in xcode

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I've successfully gone through the tutorial on using c++ in objective-C projects: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-in-an-ios-app-with-objective-c/

I wanted, however, to use hpp (and cpp) files as separate sub-project (created as cocoa touch static library project).

[image]

AllTestVC.m can see the Objective-C Files (HelloCpp.h/m), but the c++ ones are not visible. How can I solve that?

What's strange, when I cmd+click on my TestCPP object in AllTestVC, xcode properly goes to it's definition in TestCpp.hpp.

EDIT:

Files used:

AllTestVC.mm - located in main project, the one that is actually running the code from HelloCpp.h and TestCpp.hpp

HelloCpp.h/m - objC files from subproject

TestCPP.hpp/cpp - c++ files from subproject

EDIT2:

After EDIT3 this error is now not occuring: Error message is: HelloCpp/TestCpp.hpp file not found.

EDIT3:
I've added folder $(PROJECT_DIR)/HelloCpp to project's HEADER SEARCH PATHS (now all files are seen) and during build I receive error from linker:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "TestCPP::Greeting()", referenced from:
      -[ALLTestVC button1Pressed:] in ALLTestVC.o
  "TestCPP::greet()", referenced from:
      -[ALLTestVC button1Pressed:] in ALLTestVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

arm64 is included in Architectures and Valid arcitectures (both, in main project and subproject helloCpp.xcodeProj).

Comment: Try to rename HelloCpp.m to HelloCpp.mm, wich is the extension for Objective-c++'s files.

Comment: I'v edited my question - ALLTestVC was actually a .mm file

Comment: @izik461 What error are you getting? Please provide more details: error description, print-screen....

Comment: It is just a file not found error.

Comment: are the above the only errors you get? or do you actually get a ;file not found;?

Comment: As described in EDIT3 - now I receive errors from linker. Error "file not found" is now not occuring.